# Knex - Already up to date

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, migration, knex.js

I am struggling with a problem connected with the migrations in knex on the production environment (heroku). I have made some changes and created 8 new migrations to update the model. After creating new migrations I have reached 47 migration files. After uploading the changes to the Heroku I executed as usual `knex migrate:latest` and there was no effect. I have received the message `Already up to date`.

I have decided to take a look at the `knex_migrations` table to see if maybe something is wrong there. The result that I can see that the new migrations were not written into that database (please see the picture for reference.

[image]

When we take a look at the migrations it looks like this:

[image]

Clearly we can see that knex was able to run "20200216191040_receiver_company.js" as last one.

When I take a look at the `knex_migrations_lock` table the only entry that is existing over there looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to force knex to run the migrations? The version of knex that I use it `0.16.3`.

EDIT:

I want to add that on the local machine I have no problems with running the migrations. Additionally, I have checked if the migration files are present on the server and after pulling the current state our of the Heroku I can see all of the migration files that were not executed.

Answer (score 2):

If the change of the migration is not implemented in the database, you can try to manually remove the record of the migration from the `knex_migrations` or you migrations table,
and try to re-apply the `knex migrate:latest` command.

but before you try this way, make sure to keep a backup, or run it on your local machine or development server first.